# Sidebar randomly jumped from left to right, did not recall touching CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm a tad rattled simply because I cannot figure this out at all.

I am trying to make a simple page layout of a header, subheader, sidebar, content pane and footer. I scripted everything and it was working fine. I then went into my javascript file to write a function, and when I came back, my sidebar jumped from the left hand side to the right, and I simply cannot figure out why. I have tried copying my script in one section at a time, and it really seems to be only the sidebar that is bugged. Any insight would be majorly appreciated!

My HTML:

```
    <html lang ="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>....</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/styleCss.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JavaScript/dateandtime.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <a href="index.html">
            <img src="..." alt="..." height="200" width="500" />
        </a>
</div>

    <div id="subheader">
        <p id="timeStamp"><br/></p>
    </div>

    <div id="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">...</a></li>
            <li><a href="underConstruction.html">...</a></li>
            <li><a href="underConstruction.html">...</a></li>
            <li><a href="registration.html">...</a></li>
            <li><a href="underConstruction.html">...<br /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="content">content area</div>

    <div id="footer">footer</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
body{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#e3f2fd;
}

#header {
    width:1030px;
    height:200px;
    margin-left:50px;
    background-color:#2196f3;
    float:left;
}

#header img {
    float:left;
}

#header h1 {
    margin-left:550px;
    color:black;
    font-family:"arial black";
    font-size:40px;
}

#header p {
    margin-left:550px;
    color:white;
    font-family:"arial black";
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:200%;
}

#subheader {
    position:relative;
    margin-left:50px;
    width:1030px;
    height:75px;
    background-color:black;
    float:left;
    border-top:1px solid red;
}

#subheader p {
    margin-left:50px;
    color:white;
    font-family:"arial black";
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:150%;
    float: left;
}

#sidebar {
    position:relative;
    font-size:20px;
    margin-top:75px;
    background-color:#0d47a1;
    width:230px;
    height:600px;
    border:1px solid red;
    float:left;
}

#sidebar a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
}

#sidebar a:hover{
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}

#sidebar ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}

#sidebar li {
    padding-top:60px;
    padding-left:0px;
    font-family:"arial black";
}

#content {
    position:relative;
    width:798px;
    margin-top:-602px;
    margin-left: 282px;
    height:600px;
    background-color:#90caf9;
    float:left;
    border-top:1px solid red;
    border-bottom:1px solid red;

}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    height:150px;
    width:1030px;
    background-color:#82b1ff;
    margin-left:50px;
    float:left;

}
```

I would seriously appreciate any help, I must be missing something!

Comment: why do you `float: left` content? try `float: right` #content

Comment: This moves content to the right, but it goes on top of sidebar and still doesn't move it left.

Comment: can you share on JsFiddle with your js? it will easier to see the bug

Comment: check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6q8ksegk/)

Comment: Your JSFiddle doesn't show the bug you describe.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/um9tqcrv/ here you go... oddly on jsfiddle it is showing up correctly. My JS doesn't work, but that's another problem lol

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it appears on the left in your code. I will try again without using position:relative because I suppose there is where the problem comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Please wrap the all div in to one div like below and also update some css ID and class unwanted margin

```
<style type="text/css"> 
    .main-cont  {
      width: 1030px;
        float: left;
    }

    #content {
     margin-left: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    #sidebar {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
 </style> 
<body>

<div class="main-cont">
    <div id="header">
        <a href="index.html">
            <img src="..." alt="..." height="200" width="500" />
        </a>
</div>

    <div id="subheader">
        <p id="timeStamp"><br/></p>
    </div>

    <div id="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">...</a></li>
            <li><a href="underConstruction.html">...</a></li>
            <li><a href="underConstruction.html">...</a></li>
            <li><a href="registration.html">...</a></li>
            <li><a href="underConstruction.html">...<br /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="content">content area</div>

    <div id="footer">footer</div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just curious, is using the main-cont div the same idea as having your divs relative to body? I actually solved my issue from last night by having everything position:absolute which actually is what I thought position:relative meant.

Answer (score 0):

one more solution And if you don't want to add `<div class="main-cont">` try only this css

```
#subheader {
    clear: both;
    float: none;
}
```

It will set so you no need to add "main-cont" div